# AJAX GET request sending mal-formed URL string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a simple javascript / jquery AJAX request to submit a form to a php file for processing.

I want to send the parameters to the php file via GET.

If I send the parameters to the file using a manually encoded query string the processing works as expected.

An example of the query string is:

`http://example.com/processor?param_1=Dogs&param_2=Cats`

As noted above, submitting this URL works OK.

**When I make the same request using an AJAX call it fails.**

If I dump the uri string sent by the AJAX call I see that it has added all the necessary parameters, but replaced `&` in the string with `&amp;` - this change causes the call to fail (as the php file does not understand the query).

The query string sent to the AJAX call is:

`http://example.com/processor?param_1=Dog&amp;param_2=Cats`

I do not understand why the call is being made this way.

Any help with fixing would be most appreciated.

The AJAX call looks like this:

```
   function submitEdit(first_param,second_param) {
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "/content/edit",
            data: {
                param_1: first_param, 
                param_2: second_param 
            },
        });
    }
```

Thanks in advance for whatever insights you can offer.

Comment: you should use `encodeURIComponent`

Comment: or add `headers: {
            "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        }` inside ajax{} configuration

Comment: Thanks - adding `contentType` to the ajax definition does not change anything.  Not sure how you propose I apply `encodeURIComponent`- could you clarify this? Thanks!

Comment: `encodeURIComponent` can be used also but you have to create the get url manually, cannot use data{}

Comment: I got it sorted using encodeURIComponent in the end.  Thanks!